# Why aren't my trees working without line break?

Tags: line-breaking, linguistics, trees, linguex, avm

I am using the packages linguex, parsetree, and avm to make an example containing a table with two phrase structure trees. I'd like to have the table start on the same line as the example number. But when I begin the tabular environment without adding a line break, the trees aren't made.

[image: Right line, trees don't work]

Right line, trees don't work

[image: Wrong line, trees work]

Wrong line, trees work

What can I do to make the table start on the same line as the example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{linguex}
\usepackage[]{parsetree}
\usepackage[]{avm}

\begin{document}

\ex.
\begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
\begin{parsetree}
    (
    .\begin{avm}
        \[
        X \\
        Y
        \]
        \end{avm}.
    .\begin{avm}
        \[
        X \\
        Y
        \]
        \end{avm}.
    .\begin{avm}
        \[
        X \\
        Y
        \]
        \end{avm}.
    )
\end{parsetree}
&
\begin{parsetree}
    (
    .\begin{avm}
        \[
        X \\
        Y
        \]
        \end{avm}.
    .\begin{avm}
        \[
        X \\
        Y
        \]
        \end{avm}.
    .\begin{avm}
        \[
        X \\
        Y
        \]
        \end{avm}.
    )
\end{parsetree}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Where is `parsetree.sty` found? TeX Live doesn't seem to have it. And CTAN doesn't find `parsetree` either.

Comment: However, `t` will align the top of the tabular with the baseline, which probably isn't what you want. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332976/ is possibly vaguely related, but concerns `qtree` rather than `parsetree`. Since I've no idea what `parsetree` does, I don't know if the question would be helpful or not. [Disclaimer: I wrote the answer there. I remembered answering something about AVM.]

Comment: I found parsetree.sty [here](http://www.ling.helsinki.fi/kit/2003s/ctl230/LaTeX/parsetree.sty). There is a little bit of documentation [here](http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/trees/parsetree/#5), but the .sty file doesn't seem to be there anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but a recommendation, perhaps. It will probably benefit you to switch to a more modern tree-drawing package. Two popular Ti*k*Z-based packages are `tikz-qtree` and `forest`, but there are, for example, `pstricks` options, too. Of the Ti*k*Z-based options, Forest is the most powerful and flexible.

Here's a Forest-based solution which uses a modified version of the `avm` style defined in [my earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333003/) to [qtree - reduce spacing between lines in multiline node label with avm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332976/) and a variant `avm only`.

`avm only` is intended only for trees where every node is simply an `avm` environment.

`avm` is intended for trees where some nodes contain no `avm` environment or contain content before the `avm` environment. In this case, the `avm` environment should be prefixed by a `:`, with any prior content before the `:`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{avm,array,linguex}
\forestset{%
  avm/.style={%
    TeX={\setlength\extrarowheight{-10pt}},
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        split option={content}{:}{content,make avm},
      },
    },
  },
  avm only/.style={%
    TeX={\setlength\extrarowheight{-10pt}},
    before typesetting nodes={%
      for tree={%
        make pure avm,
      },
    },
  },
  make avm/.style={%
    if content={}{
      content=#1,
      make pure avm,
    }{
      content+={%
        \\\begin{avm}#1\end{avm}
      },
    },
  },
  make pure avm/.style={%
    content/.wrap value={%
      \begin{avm}##1\end{avm}
    },
    plain content,
  },
}
\begin{document}
\ex.
\begin{forest}
  avm,
  [:\[X\\Y\]
    [:\[X\\Y\]
    ]
    [:\[X\\Y\]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  avm only,
  [\[X\\Y\]
    [\[X\\Y\]
    ]
    [\[X\\Y\]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: Forest <code>avm</code> and <code>avm only</code>]

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was also able to get the right result by keeping parsetree and switching out linguex with gb4e.